# Error deploying or retrieving source for <LghtningMessageChannel> by manifest folder

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, json, lightning-message-channel

I have to deploy a messagechannel folder where there is a tag `<LightningMessageChannel>`which  I have to add at the `manifest` folder and at `package.xml`.

Now when I am deploying the below error is coming:

**The file or directory that you tried to deploy or retrieve isn't in a package directory that's specified in your sfdx-project.json file. Add this location to your "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or retrieve a different file or directory. For details about sfdx-project.json, see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.html**

I am ading nessecarry codes here-

*messageChannel-->BikeSelected.messageChannel-meta.xml*

:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    
    <description>this event is fired when bike is selected</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <description>Selected bike Id</description>
           <fieldName>bikeId</fieldName>
    </lightningMessageFields>
    <masterLabel>BikeSelected</masterLabel>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

*messageChannel-->BikesFiltered.messageChannel-meta.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    
    <description>this event is fired when bikes filter change</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <description>Current bike filters</description>
           <fieldName>filters</fieldName>
    </lightningMessageFields>
    <masterLabel>BikesFiltered</masterLabel>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

*manifest folder(at project folder not under the forceapp)-->package.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <types>
         <members>*</members>
         <name>LightningMessageChannel</name>
    </types>
    <version>57.0</version>
</Package>
```

*and the `sfdx-project.json` file is here:*

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    },
    { //It was not included , i have written this using ChatGpt
      "path": "manifest",
      "default": false
  }
  ],
  "name": "demo",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "57.0"
}
```

**I dont know where is the Fault**

[image: the directory here]

Comment: Why are you making a whole new package for this? Do you specifically want this in a new package?

Comment: no there is already a package file . I am just adding <lightningmessagechannel> to this

Comment: What I mean is, unless you are trying to create a new package, which I think you aren't, then get rid of the extra package stuff and put the metadata in with all the other metadata of the project.